# How to blend a smaller texture at certain coordinate of the source picture (a still image) using GPUImage

Tags: objective-c, gpuimage

i'm using GPUImage library and i wish to put a small logo or text at certain coordinate of a still image.

i tried using GPUImageSourceOverBlendFilter, it blends the 2nd picture into source picture but default at the center of the source picture.

Can anyone share some idea how i can achieve this?